# Group by, pivot, count and sum in DF in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a date frame with the fields PARTIDA (date), Operação (4 levels factor) and TT (numeric) .

[image: nenter image description here]

I need to group by the PARTIDA column, pivot the Operation column counting to the frequency of each level and sum the TT column.
Like this:

[image]

I already tried something with dplyr but I could not get this result, can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post the `dput` of the input example instead of an image (difficult to test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a two-step process that may get you what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- 
  tibble(
    partida = c("date1", "date2", "date3", "date1", "date2"),
    operacao = c("D", "J", "C", "D", "M"),
    tt = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  )

tt_sums <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(partida) %>% 
  count(wt = tt)

operacao_counts <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(partida, operacao) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(operacao, n) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0)

final_df <-
  operacao_counts %>% 
  left_join(tt_sums, by = "partida")

> final_df
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  partida     C     D     J     M     n
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 date1       0     2     0     0     5
2 date2       0     0     1     1     7
3 date3       1     0     0     0     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @cardinal40's answer but in one go as I try to limit the number of objects added to my environment when possible. Either answer will do the trick.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(partida) %>% 
  mutate(tt = sum(tt)) %>% 
  group_by(partida, operacao, tt) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(operacao, n) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0)
```